# Instalar OpenSSL no AWS EC2

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssl, amazon-aws

estou tentando instalar SSL num servidor Linux AWS EC2. E logo de início já estou com dificuldades.

Estou tentando, primeiramente, instalar o OpenSSL. Baixei e descompactei a versão de http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1r.tar.gz, mas agora não sei qual arquivo devo usar para instalação!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra questão é sobre o local apropriado para essa instalação. É necessário algum passo para informar um local especifico, ou posso instalar em qualquer local (por exemplo, criando um diretório "openssl" em /home/ubuntu/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui instalar o OpenSSL e gerar a chave CSR no EC2 hoje. Após baixar e descompactar o diretório, notei que estava usando o comando errado para instalar. Seguem as respostas para os dois questionamentos:

1. Para instalar, usei o comando `apt-get install openssl`
2. A saber, estou usando o SSH PUTTY
3. E sim, é possível instalar em qualquer local, sem prévia informação ou qualquer configuração específica (no meu caso, funcionou por enquanto).

Para o processo completo (que eu ainda não finalizei), estou seguindo as instruções dos seguintes links:

- http://www.deivison.com.br/instalando-o-ssl-certificado-de-seguranca-no-ec2-do-amazon-webservices/#comment-125866
- http://marlosirapuan.com/configurar-ssl-da-godaddy-na-amazon-aws-ec2-e-nginx/